# PHP: Regex to get name="" 's value

Tags: php, regex, forms

I'm still very much learning Regex and I suck at it :(

I am getting an external webpage, saving it to a local file.
The page contains a form, now I need to find all the form's input's names and put it into an array, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName">
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="something">
```

from the above I just need *firstName* to go into my array.

To complicate matters just a little bit, I have noticed people writing it a bit different sometimes because of the space character, like so:

```
name= "firstName"
name = "firstName"
name ="firstName"
```

As I am still learning, I would really appreciate it if you could explain your regex

Comment: try `\bname\b\s*=\s*"\K[^"]+(?=")`

Comment: [Do̴n͟'̡t p͞ar͜se ͟H̀T̶ML̶ ̸w͟ít͏h ͡r̡e͜g͘ex͟.͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use a HTML parser instead. For a relatively small amount of HTML it's ok, but not for what you want to achieve.

Comment: or use the `DOMdocument::getElementsByTagName` method and iterate through, grabbing the name property.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, will have a look. Andrei, will look into HTML parsers, got a recommendation? S O, isn't that Javascript?

Comment: @Ryan PHP already has HTML parsers built-in with it. Take a look at `DOMDocument` of PHP

Comment: @Ryan Nope, you can see the PHP manual page explaining how it works here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Thanks, guys! Will have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example:

```
<?PHP

$myDocument = new DOMDocument;
$myDocument->loadHTMLfile('example_page.html');

// Get form item(s)
$formItems = $myDocument->getElementsByTagName('form');

// Get input items from first form item
$inputItems = $formItems->items(0)->getElementsByTagName('input');

// Name attributes
foreach ($inputItems as $inputName) {
     echo $inputName->getAttribute('name') . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Using your example I get" Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::items()", this is the line `$inputItems = $formItems->items(0)->getElementsByTagName('input');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('REQUIRED_URL');
foreach ($xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('form') as $formitem) {
    $inputnodes = $formitem->getElementsByTagName('input');
    $name = $inputnodes->item(0)->getAttribute('name');
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting this warning (and no output other than this warning) `Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 7 and head in ...`